# Ember: How to get mouse event in a view that's not the target

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have an Ember.js application with a view where I use mouse events (down, move and up) to allow the user to resize elements by clicking and dragging while holding.
Works like a charm - until the mouse pointer leaves the boundaries of the view. Then I don't have any indication what's going on with the mouse.

To understand what I want to achieve think of the edit view in Paint - you click and drag to create a rectangle. If you pass the view's top the rectangle's height stops changing but the width changes according to the mouse current location.

I'd like to keep getting updates of the mouse moves even if the target is now another view. How can I achieve it in a clean way - without modifying the rest of the views?

Ideally, what I'd like to do is run a code in mouseLeave that modifies the way Ember's global event listener delegates events - so that they'll be passed to my view even when it's not the target. Of course - I'll need to clear this when the mouse button is released.

Answer (score 2):

Then typically you have to register the event handlers on `document` instead, and filter out the `target` to match your view.

Example using jQuery:

```
var mouseDown = false;
$(document).on("mousedown", function(e){
    // If we target the view element, we can start capture events
    var $target = $(e.target);
    if ($target.closest("#yourViewElement").length !== 0 || $target.is("#yourViewElement")) {
        mouseDown = true;
    }
});
$(document).on("mouseup", function(e){
    mouseDown = false;
});
$(document).on("mousemove", function(e){
    // We initially clicked on the view, so we listen for the changes now
    if (mouseDown) {
        // Parse events here, e.pageX / e.pageY etc.
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I thought about using this method but only if I don't find some built-in mechanism in Ember.js to achieve this. Ember already listens to these events and delegates them to the views - so I figured they might have left a way to register to this flow. I upvoted your answer but I'd like to wait for a little while before accepting it to see if someone finds a way that doesn't go around Ember but uses it instead.

Comment: One additional note - for the answer to match the question better it is required to subscribe to the events on mouseLeave and clear the subscriptions on mouseEnter (if activated) and on the mouseup handler. I'd like to avoid a permanent listener as shown in your example. Please edit and I'll mark as accepted answer.